# how to add color button to swift drawing app

Tags: swift, drawing

EDIT: I added var out of class and than changed it by button in UIview.

in my class canvas:

```
`lineColor = color`
```

out of my class, but in canvas file
    `color = UIColor.black`

in viewcontroller

`@IBAction func blue(_ sender: Any) {
        color = UIColor.blue
    }`

I'm creating a swift drawing app. I made special view for drawing(canvas) and now I created a button to change color, but it is not communicating with my canvas class in another file. I tried to add func to canvas and than call it by button, but it didn't work. Can someone help me please?

Here is my canvas.swift file

```
func blue(){

}

 class Canvas: UIView {


var lineColor:UIColor!
var lineWidth:CGFloat!
var path:UIBezierPath!
var touchPoint:CGPoint!
var startingPoint:CGPoint!


override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    lineColor = UIColor.black
    func blue(){
        lineColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    lineWidth = 7

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    startingPoint = touch?.location(in: self)
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self)

    path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: startingPoint)
    path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
    startingPoint = touchPoint

    drawShapeLayer()
}


func drawShapeLayer(){
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    self.setNeedsDisplay()


}
func clearCanvas(){
    path.removeAllPoints()
    self.layer.sublayers = nil
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: okay, but what should i do

Comment: Dont be agressive man . I dont have englih keyboard and its esier to put back apo instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this color by NSUserDefault.

To save :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(color, forKey: "colorKey")
```

To receive :

```
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "colorKey")
```

Comment: thank you, but it gives me error: Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'UIColor!'

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "colorKey") as! UIColor to convert